# iOS Swift UIImage animation got struck while doing db and webservice stuff

Tags: ios, swift

Animation Code

```
 let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotation.fromValue = 0
        rotation.toValue = 2 * Double.pi
        rotation.duration = 1.5
        rotation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        imgOuter?.layer.add(rotation, forKey: nil)



DB Code

if let image = imgDig?.image, let userLocation = self.minLocation {

                if let _ = cdHarvest { // Update
                    self.cdHarvest?.digImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(fixOrientation(img: image)) as! NSData
                    self.cdHarvest?.digDate = Date() as NSDate
                    self.cdHarvest?.digAngle = self.angleCaptured
                    self.cdHarvest?.digLat = self.minLocation.0.coordinate.latitude
                    self.cdHarvest?.digLong = self.minLocation.0.coordinate.longitude
                    CoreDataStack.saveContext()
                }
```

i am rotating a image to show it like a progress bar.while showing progress bar i am doing some stuff like inserting data into db and calling webservice.my problem is loading  bar get struck  until the process get completed.how to fix this issue.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: You have to show the code that is doing the database access and web queries, as well as the code that displays and advances your progress bar. My guess is that you are doing synchronous calls on the main thread, which will lock up the entire UI.

Comment: If you don't save the data, the animation works correctly? If that's the case, it means that you are blocking somewhere the current thread (the main one), and that's blocking the UI (since UI is done in main thread). Check if you can do it in a background thread.

Comment: can we do db stuff in background thread?if so how to do that?

Comment: @karthi I bet you are already in the background but without seeing your code it’s hard to say. The animation needs to be on the main thread